# When overriding virtual methods, is it best practice to call the base method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, polymorphism

I noticed that when overriding virtual methods in C# using Visual Studio, the IDE automatically adds the base.Method() call. On the other hand, when overriding abstract methods, the IDE automatically adds a NotImplementedException().

Why does VS automatically adds the base.Method() call when overriding virtual methods? Is it best practice to call the base method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends if you still need the base behaviour to occur. This decision would be made on a case by case basis. There's no hard and fast rule, although some patterns would expect a call to the base method (correct implementation of the [IDisposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) works this way)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio auto-generated the base class call. It is up to you to choose whether it is appropriate to call the base, it depends on your reason for overriding.

Answer (score 0):

If you completely override the method in question one could argue you have a higher risk of not following the Liskov substitution principle. But there is no general rule to follow.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract method is basically an empty method. The IDE adds not implemented exception to notify that the method is not yet implemented and it can't delegate to the base class as it would not have an implementation even there.|
In the case of the virtual method the IDE as default will call the base class implementation of that method as it will have an implementation at least there(that you will probably override)

Answer (score 0):

This depends purely on what you need to do. Often you need to include "base" method behavior into the "child" method, which is why VS helpfully adds a syntax for doing it. However, this is not necessarily the case in all situations.

On the other hand, implementing abstract method means there is no "base" method you can call (after all, it's abstract!), so the best VS can do is just "mark" the method as not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where you use te VS's code generator, but later forget (or decide not to) fill the method body in.

In case you are overriding a `virtual` method, if you didn't want to alter the behaviour in any way, the reasonable thing to do is to keep the old one - that's what the `base` call does.

On the other hand though, when you `override` an `abstract` method, you don't have any `base` to refer to - abstract methods don't have bodies by definition. 
So if you failed to provide a new implementation in an override, it always is an error. The `NotImplemented` exception draws your attention to it.

There are some patterns where you are expected to call the method (e.g. `IDisposable` or some cases of Template Method). In other cases it is desirable to always provide a new implementation, so it depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

calling base method depends what you want to do:

for example, if you override OnInit method of a control, event "Init" is not raise by default if you don't call base method. if you want change method behaviour completly you should not call base method. for instance, overridde method ToString() of StringBuilder class has his own implementation, and never call ToString of base class (object)

i think Visual studio propose base call because without other modifications all still work (base bheaviuor is not changed) 
abstract method MUST BE implemented, and throw exception as default statement should help you to remeinder proper implementation

Answer (score -3):

Adding a call like this it doesn´t modify the method behavior.